# setup.py doesn't seem to be recognizing my libs trying to build python 2.7.3

Tags: python

I'm trying to build *python 2.7.3* and run it out of my home folder.  *Linux Mint Olivia* (based off of Ubuntu 13.04).  I've run the following:

```
cd   #go home
curl -O http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
tar xzfv Python-2.7.3.tgz 
cd Python-2.7.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

It does all of this, and installs to `~/bin/`, but the problem I'm running into is that it's not picking up the libraries for some of the 'optional' stuff, like *bz2* or *ssl*.  I have *libbz2-dev* installed.  I tried mucking around in *setup.py* and took out the part where it tests for the *bz2* stuff and rigged it so that it assumed success.  The *bz2module* then compiled successfully, and executes properly.

Problem is I don't want to go and toy around with *setup.py* for all the stuff I have installed if I can avoid doing that.  I tried peering into the distutils code to see what was going wrong, but I'm pretty far out of my depth there.  I'm not sure even how to diagnose this.

Also maybe worth noting I had no problems using the exact same method on an Ubuntu 12.04 system.

Anyways, pointers, tips, or fresh ideas on where to look for the problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked this down finally, thought I'd share.  Not a complete answer, but enough of one to work with.

From setup.py, the lib_dirs on the ubuntu install included the folder:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so

The mint install did not include the same folder.  I added it manually in setup.py and everything started working.  I have no idea *why* it's not included, but if you stumbled across this for a similar reason, adding it may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

was there a deb in the repositories of ubuntu for that ? or in your mint distros ?
try `sudo apt-get install python`
by default python will only install the version 2.7.5+ for python 3.3 you just use `sudo apt-get install python3`
assuming you only want to install the version 2.
else 
your commands seams alright for ubuntu, but there is a lot of difference for Mint, you should post in the linux mint forums. they know more their version